# is wired network card defect

Tags: ethernet

Ubuntu 18.04
Wireless is working. Recently I found out wired network card is not working, I suspect it is defect but how to confirm? I've checked everything, cable etc. It is either disabled or defect.
On askubuntu I found post with commands `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" && sudo lshw | grep -A5 "Moth" && lshw | grep product | head -n1 && cat /proc/net/dev && lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3 && sudo lshw -class network && nmcli`, that I ran, but cannot interpret myself. here is output:

```
description: Motherboard
       product: EA50_HW
       vendor: Acer
       physical id: 0
       version: V2.13
       serial: NBMFM1100941268E373400
       product: Intel(R) Celeron(R) 2955U @ 1.40GHz
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
enp1s0f0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
    lo:  630073    6623    0    0    0     0          0         0   630073    6623    0    0    0     0       0          0
wlp2s0: 71698339   64036    0    0    0     0          0         0  5743787   36275    0    0    0     0       0          0
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57786 
Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b3] (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
01:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev ff)
  *-generic:0               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Illegal Vendor ID
       vendor: Illegal Vendor ID
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0f0
       version: ff
       serial: f8:a9:63:05:3d:ba
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=sb latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 memory:b0410000-b041ffff memory:b0420000-b042ffff memory:9fb00000-9fb007ff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: 14:2d:27:1a:3e:05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.4.0-52-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.34 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:b0500000-b057ffff memory:b0580000-b058ffff
wlp2s0: connected to deki20
        "Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter"
        wifi (ath9k), 14:2D:27:1A:3E:05, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 192.168.0.34/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        route4 192.168.0.0/24
        route4 169.254.0.0/16
        inet6 fe80::4343:1c0e:4cd0:43a/64
        route6 ff00::/8
        route6 fe80::/64
        route6 fe80::/64

enp1s0f0: unavailable
        "Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM57786 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe"
        ethernet (tg3), F8:A9:63:05:3D:BA, hw, mtu 1500

lo: unmanaged
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

DNS configuration:
        servers: 193.162.153.164 194.239.134.83
        domains: home
        interface: wlp2s0

Use "nmcli device show" to get complete information about known devices and
"nmcli connection show" to get an overview on active connection profiles.

Consult nmcli(1) and nmcli-examples(5) manual pages for complete usage details.
lines 8-30/30 (END)
```

In settings-->network it says cable unplugged (the cable is though plugged in), and I can't turn it on with slider. Also it says last used 55 days ago. (I've test it/used it before). Another thing is that the light, that should be on, when the cable is plugged in, is off.

Comment: You have verified that your cable is working (today)? Or tried a different (known-working) cable? Half of my network hardware problems are cables-gone-bad (trod upon, rolled over, pinched by furniture, etc). The first thing I do is replace the old cable with a freshly-tested cable.

Comment: you can try to start the ethernet manually by using: sudo modprobe "the name of your ethernet driver" (without the quotes of course). If it starts, then it means there is nothing wrong with your card. Then you need to make it permanent. 
see here for some example: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/11/modprobe-command-examples/

Comment: I've checked the cable again. it's working, comes up with 'wired connected' after I plugged into desktop. (the problem is on laptop). I've run lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net, and got 'kernel drive in use: tg3'. Then sudo mobprobe tg3. Non reaction. not even a letter. think card is no longer functional